# Клик по input[type="file"]

Tags: html, javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/ZhmUw/

Пытался сделать через position: absolute, чтобы при клике на ссылку, кликалось и по type="file", но ничего не вышло. Если делать это на js:

```
document.getElementById('file').click;
```

то в некоторых браузерах не работает, поэтому такой вариант не катит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я делаю так (или [button](https://github.com/mailru/FileAPI/#button))

```css
.upload-link {
  color: #36c;
  display: inline-block;
  *zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.upload-link__txt {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #36c;
}

.upload-link:hover .upload-link__txt {
  color: #f00;
  border-bottom-color: #f00;
}

.upload-link__inp {
  top: -10px;
  right: -40px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<a class="upload-link js-fileapi-wrapper">
  <span class="upload-link__txt">Upload photo</span>
  <input class="upload-link__inp" name="photo" type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.gif" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

Стандартный способ - решать через label

```css
label.uploadbutton input {
  display: none;
}

label.uploadbutton .button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px  solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label.uploadbutton .button:active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<label class="uploadbutton">
  <div class="button">Upload</div>
  <input type="file"/>
</label>
```

Comment: Это не кросс браузерно, например Opera 12.15 не понимает этого.
P.S. Хотя, через opacity уже начинает работать.

Comment: по идее должно всегда работать с триггером click, но надо это делать в том же потоке (или как там) что и хэндлер клика, в последний раз у меня от IE6 это работало.

Comment: вот для оперы, http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/tP8d9/4/

Comment: Вообще способ клевый и почему то встречаю его первый раз, спасибо.

Comment: @RubaXa это кстати странно, label он ведь для того и придуман...

Comment: @eicto, просто попробуй те поискать в гугле стилизацию input[type="file"], этот способ отсутствует, либо я дыркаглаз.

Answer (score 0):

> Пытался сделать через position:
> absolute, чтобы при клике на ссылку,
> кликалось и по type="file", но ничего
> не вышло. Если делать это на js:
>
> document.getElementById('file').click;
>
> то в некоторых браузерах не работает,
> поэтому такой вариант не катит.

Ну конечно такой способ не сработает. Данный код возвращает функцию, а не вызывает.
А для вызова:

```
document.getElementById('file').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<label for="upload_img">Upload</label>
<form style="display:none;" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" id="upload_img" name="photo">
</form>
```